# How to properly submit only one form in table of ModelForms in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I need to create a table of forms for creating and updating users based on my custom User model. It must look something like this:
[image]
Form is presented as particular row in table.
`Save` button saves submits form, `Delete` removes form and the model instance from database, `Add` button appends new blank form to end of `<tbody>` but to save new form we need to click `Save` button.

Now I'm stuck and don't know how to properly implement logic above. I need each form to be updated and submitted independently. I looked up for solutions based on ModelFormSet but it submits all forms and does not allow to update only one particular row of data.

How we can create prepopulated ModelFormSet where each row of form data can be submitted regardless of other forms in table? Like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="username" value="admin" maxlength="255" class="login-input" id="id_username" /></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="password" value="" maxlength="128" class="password-input" id="id_password" /></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" class="email-input" id="id_email" /></td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="active" class="checkbox-input" id="id_active" checked /></td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="staff" class="checkbox-input" id="id_staff" checked /></td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="reboot_field" class="checkbox-input" id="id_reboot_field" checked /></td>
<td><button type="submit" form="form1">Save</button></td>
<td><button form="form1" >Delete</button></td>
<tr>
</form> 
<form action="" method="post">
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="username" value="user1" maxlength="255" class="login-input" id="id_username" /></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="password" value="" maxlength="128" class="password-input" id="id_password" /></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" class="email-input" id="id_email" /></td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="active" class="checkbox-input" id="id_active" checked /></td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="staff" class="checkbox-input" id="id_staff" checked /></td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="reboot_field" class="checkbox-input" id="id_reboot_field" checked /></td>
<td><button type="submit" form="form2" >Save</button></td>
<td><button form="form2">Delete</button></td>
<tr>
</form>
```

Comment: try to send this form with javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution based on [this](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/) link.